# Trouble with formatting Tkinter python 3

Tags: python, datagrid, tkinter

So my program works, but the formatting is so off and I don't understand how to make it look neat.

I tried different combinations of grid but nothing seems to work. [It just looks really sloppy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtSXq.png) and I am not quite sure what can be done.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import ttk

main = Tk()
frame = Frame(main) 
text = Text(main, height=10, width=20)

def complex_password():
    password2 = []
    password2.append(random.choice((captial)))
    count = 0
    x = ""
    while count != 12:
        roll = random.randint(1,4)
        if roll == 1 or roll == 2:
            password2.append(random.choice((letters)))
            count +=1
        if roll == 3 or roll == 4:
            number = random.randint(0,9)
            number = str(number)
            password2.append(number)
            count +=1
        if count == 12:
            password2 = x.join(password2)
            text.insert(INSERT, password2)
            text.insert(INSERT, "\n")

def simple_password():
    y = ""
    password1 = []
    password1.append(random.choice((words)))
    password1.append(random.choice((words)))
    number = random.randint(1,99)
    num = str(number)
    password1.append(num)
    password1 = y.join(password1)
    text.insert(INSERT, password1)
    text.insert(INSERT, "\n")

def clear_text():
    dele = text.delete(1.0, END)
    text.insert(dele)

label = Label(frame, text="Password Generator!!")

simple = Button(frame, text="Simple", command=simple_password)
complex = Button(frame, text="Complex", command=complex_password)
clear = Button(frame, text="Clear", command=clear_text)

text.grid(row=2, column=2)
label.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=1)
simple.grid(row=2, column=1)
complex.grid(row=2, column=2)
clear.grid(row=2, column=3)
frame.grid(column=2, row=1)

main.configure(bg="blue3")
frame.configure(bg="blue3")

words = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Fire', 'Ice', 'Basket', 'Tree', 'Tiger',      'Lion', 'Flash', 'Super', 'Light', 'Zoom',
     'Speed', 'Pants', 'Shirt', 'Hat', 'Suit', 'Berry', 'Yogurt', 'Epic',   'Keyboard', 'Toe', 'Car', 'Truck', 'Bike', 'Motor', 'Hammer', 'Pizza', 'Heart', 'Arm',
     'Joint', 'Sawg', 'New', 'Carrots', 'Baby', 'Kiss', 'Backspace', 'Enter', 'Alt', 'Print', "Down", 'Up', 'Question', 'Rain', 'Forest',
     'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Black', 'Indigo', 'Grey', 'Shadow', 'Eye', 'Brick', 'Twig',
     'Gangster', 'Thug', 'Chains', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze', 'Platinum', 'Titanium', 'Exploding', 'Ladybug', 'Grass',
     'Monkey', 'Rhino', 'Comma', 'Hair', 'Shark', 'Fish']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
captial = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have a question: why, in `clear_text()` do you have a call to `text.insert()`?  It produces an error and doesn't seem to have any real use.

Comment: What do you want to change about the formatting?

Comment: I want the buttons to line up and not have the spaces

Comment: Do you want them centered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the buttons centered, then this is my suggestion:  add a new frame within the outer frame and grid it with `row=2` and `column=2`; then put all of your buttons in that frame instead of the outer frame.  This is the result:

[image: Screenshot]
This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from tkinter import ttk 

main = Tk()
frame = Frame(main) 
buttonframe = Frame(frame)
text = Text(main, height=10, width=20)

def complex_password():
    password2 = []
    password2.append(random.choice((captial)))
    count = 0 
    x = ""
    while count != 12: 
        roll = random.randint(1,4)
        if roll == 1 or roll == 2:
            password2.append(random.choice((letters)))
            count +=1 
        if roll == 3 or roll == 4:
            number = random.randint(0,9)
            number = str(number)
            password2.append(number)
            count +=1
        if count == 12:
            password2 = x.join(password2)
            text.insert(INSERT, password2)
            text.insert(INSERT, "\n")

def simple_password():
    y = ""
    password1 = []
    password1.append(random.choice((words)))
    password1.append(random.choice((words)))
    number = random.randint(1,99)
    num = str(number)
    password1.append(num)
    password1 = y.join(password1)
    text.insert(INSERT, password1)
    text.insert(INSERT, "\n")

def clear_text():
    dele = text.delete(1.0, END)

label = Label(frame, text="Password Generator!!")
simple = Button(buttonframe, text="Simple", command=simple_password)
complex = Button(buttonframe, text="Complex", command=complex_password)
clear = Button(buttonframe, text="Clear", command=clear_text)

text.grid(row=2, column=2)
label.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=1)
simple.grid(row=2, column=1)
complex.grid(row=2, column=2)
clear.grid(row=2, column=3)
frame.grid(column=2, row=1)
buttonframe.grid(row=2, column=2)

main.configure(bg="blue3")
frame.configure(bg="blue3")

words = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse', 'Fire', 'Ice', 'Basket', 'Tree', 'Tiger',      'Lion', 'Flash', 'Super', 'Light', 'Zoom',
     'Speed', 'Pants', 'Shirt', 'Hat', 'Suit', 'Berry', 'Yogurt', 'Epic',   'Keyboard', 'Toe', 'Car', 'Truck', 'Bike', 'Motor', 'Hammer', 'Pizza', 'Heart', 'Arm',
     'Joint', 'Sawg', 'New', 'Carrots', 'Baby', 'Kiss', 'Backspace', 'Enter', 'Alt', 'Print', "Down", 'Up', 'Question', 'Rain', 'Forest',
     'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Black', 'Indigo', 'Grey', 'Shadow', 'Eye', 'Brick', 'Twig', 
     'Gangster', 'Thug', 'Chains', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze', 'Platinum', 'Titanium', 'Exploding', 'Ladybug', 'Grass',
     'Monkey', 'Rhino', 'Comma', 'Hair', 'Shark', 'Fish']
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
captial = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: i did that and my buttons dont fit the screen like that, and the text box is all the way to the left

Comment: I just added the code to my answer.  Does it match yours?

Comment: I can't explain it; the screenshot is of the window created by that code.

Comment: i ss what it looks like see original post

Comment: I believe the reason for the difference is that on your computer, the text box is wider than the buttons, but on mine it is narrower.  If I expand my window, everything stays in the same place; there's just more blue one the right.  If you make your window smaller, you should see something similar to mine.  You might consider setting the size of your window explicitly, so that everything looks normal.